Is this property of Mahlo cardinals correct?
Quoting from a paper discussing large cardinals:
for any ρ that is a Mahlo cardinal, there must also exist ρ smaller cardinals (call them κ, with
all κ < ρ) that are k-inaccessible, hyper k-inaccessible,and so on for all subsequent tiers of inaccessibility ,
with all of those smaller κ’s not being Mahlo.
Is this correct and how would you prove this?

I don't understand the content of "with all of those smaller $\kappa$'s not being Mahlo". Are you interested in showing that there are hyper-inaccessibles of all sorts beneath any Mahlo, or that there are hyper-inaccessibles that are not Mahlo? Certainly if we consider any Mahlo other than the least, it won't be the case that all hyper inaccessibles beneath aren't Mahlo, but the fact that there is a least Mahlo and that any Mahlo has hyper-inaccessibles beneath shows that not all hyper-inaccessibles are Mahlo.

@spaceisdarkgreen I think this is about the least mahlo cardinal. If  is ρ the least mahlo then it is not the first cardinal that is inaccessible hyperinaccessible and so on but the ρ-th cardinal if I am understanding this correctly.

You may want to just consult a book for that... if I recall correctly the old large cardinals book by Drake has a detailed treatment of this sort of thing. The general idea is that e.g. the inaccessibles are the regular strong limits, and the strong limits beneath $\kappa$ are a club, so the inaccessibles beneath $\kappa$ are stationary. Then the 1-inaccessibles are the regular limits of inaccessibles, and the limit points of the unbounded set of inaccessibles beneath $\kappa$ are a club, so the 1-inaccessibles beneath $\kappa$ are stationary, and so on.
